# parse email using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

I am looking for some direction for how to parse an email using nokogiri.  Below is a sample email. I have reviewed this document http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html and hours of googleing.  I am new at Ruby on Rails and am looking for a great example or detailed instructions.  Thank you for your time.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.76.129.52; Mon, 30 Apr 2012 22:11:24 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 22:11:24 -0700
Message-ID: <CAJq2oOCB-UzNEFGc+3TVBSEA0L9VPRrjevhdW_KK41C+AGDjJw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Customize Gmail with colors and themes
From: Gmail Team <mail-noreply@google.com>
To: parse email <parseemail2@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec545501825242f04bef29a74

--bcaec545501825242f04bef29a74
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

To spice up your inbox with colors and themes, check out the Themes tab
under Settings.
       Customize Gmail =BB <https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/themes>


Enjoy!

- The Gmail Team
[image: Themes thumbnails]

Please note that Themes are not available if you're using Internet Explorer
6.0. To take advantage of the latest Gmail features, please upgrade to a
fully supported
browser<http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=3D6557&hl=3Den&=
utm_source=3Dwel-eml&utm_medium=3Deml&utm_campaign=3Den>
.

--bcaec545501825242f04bef29a74
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<p>To spice up your inbox with colors and themes, check out the Themes tab
under Settings.</p>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <col style="width: 1px;"/>
  <col/>
  <col style="width: 1px;"/>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td height="1px" style="background-color: #ddd"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ddd"></td>
    <td background="https://mail.google.com/mail/images/welcome-button-background.png"
        style="background-color: #ddd; background-repeat: repeat-x;
            padding: 10px; font-size: larger">
          <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/themes"
            style="font-weight: bold; color: #000; text-decoration: none;
            display: block;">
      Customize Gmail &#187;</a>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #ddd"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td height="1px" style="background-color: #ddd"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Enjoy!</p>

<p>- The Gmail Team</p>

<img width="398" height="256" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/images/gmail_themes_2.png"
alt="Themes thumbnails" />

<p><font size="-2" color="#999">Please note that Themes are not available if
you're using Internet Explorer 6.0. To take advantage of the latest Gmail
features, please
<a href="http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6557&hl=en&utm_source=wel-    
eml&utm_medium=eml&utm_campaign=en"><font color="#999">
upgrade to a fully supported browser</font></a>.</font></p>

</font>
</html>

--bcaec545501825242f04bef29a74--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri works great for parsing HTML, but what you have here is an email. Try using [TMail](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/) to first get the HTML section from the email, then you can use Nokogiri to parse that. Extrapolating from the TMail docs, you could do something like:

```
  email = TMail::Mail.load('my_email.eml')
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(email.body)
```

Comment: Is there another way other than using TMail to get the HTML section?

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't know how to read emails, only HTML/XML-formatted content. As emails have headers, content-type partitions, and more, you have to strip all of that cruft out before parsing them as HTML.


You *could*, in theory, try some custom regex-based (eeks!) strategy to find the `Content-Type: text/html` line, but that's fragile and tricky to do.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I was asked to figure it out without TMail.  Sounds kind of crazy.